# [Flutter IOS]:Why would I get "OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1" when trying to read or write a file in the applications docs dir?

Tags: flutter

I use Flutter and path_provider to get the applicationsDocumentsDirectory.

I then create a file (if it does not exist) in a sub-directory and try to read or write the file. Most of the time it works, but randomly we get an error on IOS devices:

FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E3B02F0F-EEB2-4FCC-9774-8D6B6A4CCD0D/Documents/subfolder1/subfolder2/collection.0' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)

I use Flutter and path_provider to get the applicationsDocumentsDirectory.

The code is straightforward

```
final docsDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String dirPath = dir.path + "/subfolder1/subfolder2";
Directory dir = Directory(dirPath);
if(!await dir.exists()) {
  dir = await dir.create(recursive: true);
}

File collectionFile = new File(dirPath + "/collection.0");
if(!await collectionFile.exists()) {
   collectionFile = await collectionFile.create();
}
```

// After this, the code could read or write (based on some conditions) and this read or write now fails for some users randomly, and throws the exception shown below

```
String? strFile = await collectionFile.readAsString();
```

(or)

```
await collectionFile.writeAsString(strFile, flush: true);
```

Why would this happen? I tried adding a check for file.existsSync() before reading or writing the file. existsSync() returns true, yet I still get the error.

The error I get is:

FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E3B02F0F-EEB2-4FCC-9774-8D6B6A4CCD0D/Documents/subfolder1/subfolder2/collection.0' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)

Answer (score 0):

dir.path in your code should change to docsDir.path

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That was just a typo in my sample here .. in actual code, it was obviously the right variable name as it wouldnt have compiled without it.